# CodeIgniter routes 2 parameters

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I've tried to create an app using routes but when I pass 2 parameters, nothing happens. The function is not fired.

When I use 1 param, it works:

```
$route['category_(:any)'] = 'category/categoryDetails/$1';
$route['category_(:any)/(:any)'] = 'category/categoryDemandeDetails/$1/$2';
```

and in my controller:

```
public function categoryDetails($name){
    $data = array('page' => 'category', 'categoryName' => $name);
    $this->load->view('category', $data);
}
public function categoryDemandeDetails($name, $demande){
    $data = array('page' => 'category',  'categoryName' => $name);
    $this->load->view('demande', $data);
}
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: What happens if you swap the order of those routes (move the first below the second)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first route will be catching all of the requests that start with `category_`, including any that should be routed to the second route. This is because `(:any)` will catch *anything*, including multiple parameters, so the second route would never be used in this order.

> Routes will run in the order they are defined. Higher routes will always take precedence over lower ones.

You just need to change the order of the routes:

```
$route['category_(:any)/(:any)'] = 'category/categoryDemandeDetails/$1/$2';
$route['category_(:any)'] = 'category/categoryDetails/$1';
```